# A fatal error occurred, the required library libhostfxr.dylib could not be found

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

While trying to add authentication to a .net core app on mac, using this command :

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -h
```

I receive this error :

> Macintosh-2:Website abd$ dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -h A
>   fatal error occurred, the required library libhostfxr.dylib could not
>   be found. If this is a self-contained application, that library should
>   exist in
>   [/Users/abd/.dotnet/tools/.store/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator/2.2.3/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator/2.2.3/tools/netcoreapp2.1/any/].
>   If this is a framework-dependent application, install the runtime in
>   the default location [/usr/local/share/dotnet] or use the DOTNET_ROOT
>   environment variable to specify the runtime location. M

Answer (score 9):

For Mac M1 processor, the .NET libraries are not located in the default install location `"usr/local/share/dotnet"`; but rather in one of its sub-directories `"./x64"`.

You have to set the `DOTNET_ROOT` environment variable to point to that sub-directory.

`export DOTNET_ROOT=/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64`

*I guess this same solution could be scaled beyond the M1 processor, so long you set DOTNET_ROOT to whatever directory contains libhostfxr.xx*

Comment: There is no such `x64` directory on my M1 Mac. Just did a fresh install of the latest dotnet 6 and no luck.

Comment: there shouldn't be one. The doc says: On an Arm-based Mac, all Arm64 versions of .NET are installed to the normal /usr/local/share/dotnet/ folder. However, when you install the x64 version of .NET 7 SDK, it's installed to the /usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet/ folder. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/macos?tabs=netcore2x#path-differences

Answer (score 6):

This solved it for me:

```
dotnet tool uninstall dotnet-ef --global
dotnet tool install dotnet-ef --global -a arm64
```

Comment: This is the answer that solved a similar problem for me when running "dotnet ef migrations add".  My error message was "Failed to load /usr/local/share/dotnet/host/fxr/7.0.3/libhostfxr.dylib"

Comment: this should have been the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

Dotnet executable will be present at $DOTNET_ROOT which you can find with `which dotnet` or

```
readlink $(which dotnet)
```

A successful dotnet installation will have the `libhostfxr.dylib` file at `$DOTNET_ROOT/host/fxr/$version/`

If so, it is a permission issue and running with sudo will do.

```
sudo dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -h
```

[Ref](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/2958)

Comment: I have the same problem but with file libhostfxr.so. "which dotnet" returns "/home/pi/dotnet/dotnet" and libhostfxr.so is present at /dotnet/host/fxr/5.0.6  and I am running the app with sudo at the start but still get the error.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem (.Net SDK 7 on m1). Nothing worked for me until I figured out that target framework of my app was `3.1` and the 3.1 runtime does not exist in arm version. So SDK could build but could NOT start. Changed the target to be `<TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>` and it works, as simple as that.
I think installing x86 version of framework would've also worked via Rosetta, but I would not pollute my machine to check this.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue with running the Omnisharp language server on an M1 Mac. The solution for me was to set the `DOTNET_ROOT` environment variable to the correct global dotnet location. For me this was `/usr/local/share/dotnet`.

I also needed to update the contents of `/etc/dotnet/install_location`. I noticed that there were two files in `/etc/dotnet`.

1. `install_location`
2. `install_location_arm64`

The `install_location_arm64` contained the correct path to dotnet (`/usr/local/share/dotnet`), but `install_location` contained `/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64` which doesn't exist. After updating the contents of `install_location` to `/usr/local/share/dotnet`, the problem was solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed/uninstalled .net frameworks on your machine maybe the links are looking in the wrong folder.

check dotnet location with the command **which dotnet**
eg the location should be something like that:
/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet

Afterwards, check the file **/etc/dotnet/install_location**
should contain one line with the above path.

Comment: My install_location file points to a non-existent folder: `/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64`